# Get webflux event-loop scheduler

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I use **webflux** with **netty** and **jdbc**, so I wrap blocking jdbc operation the next way:

```
static <T> Mono<T> fromOne(Callable<T> blockingOperation) {
    return Mono.fromCallable(blockingOperation)
        .subscribeOn(jdbcScheduler)
        .publishOn(Schedulers.parallel());
}
```

Blocking operation will be processed by the **jdbcScheduler**, and I want the other pipeline will be proccesed by **webflux event-loop scheduler**.

How to get webflux event-loop scheduler?

Answer (score 5):

I will strongly advise to revisit the technology options. If you are going to use jdbc, which is still blocking, then you should not use webflux. This is because webflux will shine in a non-blocking stack but coupled with Jdbc it will act as a bottleneck. The performance will actually go down.

Comment: Thanks, I understand this, because of it we wrap blocking operations the way I describe in question.

Comment: Yes, but the overall performance will still go down significantly.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Vikram Rawat use jdbc is very dangerous mainly because jdbc is a bocking IO api and use an event loop reactive model is very dangerous because basically it is very easy block all the server.

However, even if it is an experimental effort I suggest you to stay tuned to R2DBC project that is able to leverage a no blocking api for sql I used it for a spike and it is very elegant.

I can provide you an example taken from a my home project on github based on sprign boot 2.1 and kotlin:

**web layer**

```
@Configuration
class ReservationRoutesConfig {

    @Bean
    fun reservationRoutes(@Value("\${baseServer:http://localhost:8080}") baseServer: String,
                          reservationRepository: ReservationRepository) =
            router {
                POST("/reservation") {
                    it.bodyToMono(ReservationRepresentation::class.java)
                            .flatMap { Mono.just(ReservationRepresentation.toDomain(reservationRepresentation = it)) }
                            .flatMap { reservationRepository.save(it).toMono() }
                            .flatMap { ServerResponse.created(URI("$baseServer/reservation/${it.reservationId}")).build() }

                }

                GET("/reservation/{reservationId}") {
                    reservationRepository.findOne(it.pathVariable("reservationId")).toMono()
                            .flatMap { Mono.just(ReservationRepresentation.toRepresentation(it)) }
                            .flatMap { ok().body(BodyInserters.fromObject(it)) }
                }

                DELETE("/reservation/{reservationId}") {
                    reservationRepository.delete(it.pathVariable("reservationId")).toMono()
                            .then(noContent().build())
                }
            }
}
```

**repository layer:**

```
class ReactiveReservationRepository(private val databaseClient: TransactionalDatabaseClient,
                                    private val customerRepository: CustomerRepository) : ReservationRepository {

    override fun findOne(reservationId: String): Publisher<Reservation> =
            databaseClient.inTransaction {
                customerRepository.find(reservationId).toMono()
                        .flatMap { customer ->
                            it.execute().sql("SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE reservation_id=$1")
                                    .bind("$1", reservationId)
                                    .exchange()
                                    .flatMap { sqlRowMap ->
                                        sqlRowMap.extract { t, u ->
                                            Reservation(t.get("reservation_id", String::class.java)!!,
                                                    t.get("restaurant_name", String::class.java)!!,
                                                    customer, t.get("date", LocalDateTime::class.java)!!)
                                        }.one()
                                    }
                        }
            }

    override fun save(reservation: Reservation): Publisher<Reservation> =
            databaseClient.inTransaction {
                customerRepository.save(reservation.reservationId, reservation.customer).toMono()
                        .then(it.execute().sql("INSERT INTO reservation (reservation_id, restaurant_name, date) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)")
                                .bind("$1", reservation.reservationId)
                                .bind("$2", reservation.restaurantName)
                                .bind("$3", reservation.date)
                                .fetch().rowsUpdated())
            }.then(Mono.just(reservation))


    override fun delete(reservationId: String): Publisher<Void> =
            databaseClient.inTransaction {
                customerRepository.delete(reservationId).toMono()
                        .then(it.execute().sql("DELETE FROM reservation WHERE reservation_id = $1")
                                .bind("$1", reservationId)
                                .fetch().rowsUpdated())
            }.then(Mono.empty())

}
```

I hope that can help you